# I can log the data but can't render in React and Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm working on this component:

```js
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import FutureJobItem from "./FutureJobItem";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import {
  setLoading,
  getCalendarEvents,
} from "../../../../store/actions/calendarActions";

const FutureJobsList = ({
  events,
  gradient,
  loading,
  setLoading,
  getCalendarEvents,
}) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    setLoading();
    getCalendarEvents();
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, []);
  return (
    <div>
      {events !== null && !loading ? (
        events.map((item, index) => {
          console.log(item);
          console.log(index);
          console.log(item.title);
          return <h1 key={item.token}>{item.title}</h1>;
        })
      ) : (
        <h1>no data</h1>
      )}
      <FutureJobItem gradient={gradient[12]} />
    </div>
  );
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    events: state.calendar.events,
    gradient: state.calendar.gradient,
    loading: state.calendar.loading,
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { setLoading, getCalendarEvents })(
  FutureJobsList,
);
```

I can successfully log the data that is inside map and in the same time `<h1>no data</h1>` is rendering and `<h1 key={item.token}>{item.title}</h1>`  is not.
Somehow It's validate both conditions.
If `events !== null && !loading` this condition take place so why can't render anything?
If It's not so why It's logging the data?
what is the problem?

Comment: Are you sure you're not seeing two consecutive renders of the component, one first logging your things, then another with no data?

Comment: No that's not the problem. It's just rendering no data no matter what

Comment: hi @MahmoodNajafi, did you manage to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

```js
      {events !== null && !loading ? (
        events.map((item, index) => (
             <h1 key={item.token}>{item.title}</h1>;
        ))
      ) : (
        <h1>no data</h1>
      )}
```

This is the only piece of code I suspect is wrong, try changing the {} inside the map to () and remove the return statement.It thas to do with returning JSX

Comment: It's the same thing ; I have another logic to do there and because of that I used {}